# Same representation for GET and PUT?

Tags: rest, http

As other people (for example: [here](http://soabits.blogspot.de/2013/01/http-put-patch-or-post-partial-updates.html)) I'm struggling with the question, if the representation for [GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) and [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) should be the same?

**Example:**

GET representation:

```
{
    "id": "0815",
    "name": "jdoe",
    "emailAddress": "jd@example.com",
    "displayName": "John Doe",
    "active": true
}
```

PUT representation:

```
{
    "emailAddress": "jd@example.com",
    "displayName": "John Doe"
}
```

**Research:**

I read in [REST question: PUT one representation, GET a different one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944029/rest-question-put-one-representation-get-a-different-one) that it is ok, to get another media type with GET as I saved with PUT.

I read in [REST - put IDs in body or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900041/rest-put-ids-in-body-or-not) that it is ok, to omit the id with PUT and get the id with GET.

I read in [GET Representation != POST Representation](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/rest/different-representations) that it is ok, to omit a lot of properties with PUT and get them with GET. An example is [JIRA REST API - api/2/myself](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/myself). GET returns the hole user model and PUT saves only 3 properties.

Is that good practice? I could also use [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2), for example [GitHub REST API - users](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/). What's the reason to add PATCH to HTTP, if PUT with another smaller representation is already enough?

Further more I read in [Best practice for partial updates in a RESTful service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443324/best-practice-for-partial-updates-in-a-restful-service) that most big REST APIs (for example: [Google](http://googlecode.blogspot.de/2010/03/making-apis-faster-introducing-partial.html)) use PATCH or [POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) for partial updates and PUT only for complete/full updates (for example: [Goolge - Updating an entity](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/basics#UpdatingEntry)).

Answer (score 5):

The idea is that the server generally has more information about the resource than the user, and so GET *might* return more information than is required for PUT. There are some things which the server 'owns', and so cannot be updated by the client. These can be returned by GET while the PUT representation does not allow the user to modify them.

However, that's not the same thing as saying that PUT allows you to partially update the resource. When you PUT a document you update all of the values which that document covers - so an 'optional' value which is not present in the actual document sent via PUT should be *removed* from the resource. When you do a subsequent GET on that resource, the optional value will not be present.

The semantics of [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) are supposed to be slightly different - with PATCH the client sends a *partial* update which describes changes in some way. Those changes are then applied to the resource in some fashion. Parts of the resource which are not mentioned in the document sent via PATCH will be unmodified.

Also, note that PATCH is explicitly defined as *neither* safe nor idempotent. Whereas PUT is idempotent but not safe - the same request repeated will result in the same change. With a PATCH, some changes could be cumulative (e.g. add a value to a list) and so duplicated requests could result in a different state of the resource.

Comment: If PUT can`t make partial updates, the question is, what is the full representation of the resource? If I understand you right, it is not the representation of GET, it is less than this. But how is it defined and in which RFC?

Comment: There doesn't *have* to be a 'full' representation of a resource. It may be that with different media-types you get different information, with each media type offering a facet of the resource. There's nothing wrong with that. Imagine the difference between an image-type representation (image/jpeg) and a text representation (application/json), for example.

Comment: this is not correct. the GET and PUT should represent the same resource.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with this *exact* same question. Thanks for your research into it and for articulating it well. I think the issue here is that there is data that *has* to be determined/created by the server/backend that REST hasn't really addressed a best practice for. For example:

- GUID's
- Unique/Sequential Ids
- Timestamps

In every trivial REST example you see it appears to be pretty symmetrical between what you GET vs what you POST/PUT. For example, REST would lead you to believe that if you do a GET on a collection (or resource) and then POST (or PUT) that response body back that there should be no change, but that's just not realistic considering the aforementioned examples. So in essence your GET response becomes a superset of the actual POST/PUT body.

The terminology I've used for this as a head nod to the relational asymmetry between the two has been to say that my GET returns a Readonly representation of the collection/resource, versus that the POST/PUT body accepts. That lends itself nicely to code where you can inherit a `Readonly` representation from the object to augment it with the properties that your server/backend is responsible for creating/managing. For example, here's two TypeScript interfaces showing what data a user could PUT (`IPet`) versus what data the server would respond with for a GET (`IReadonlyPet`)

```
interface IPet {
    name: string, // The user can change the pet's name
}
interface IReadonlyPet extends IPet {
    id: number,  // The user should not be able to change the pet's id
}
```

I don't know if I'd force a user to strip off things like `id` when making a POST/PUT subsequent to a GET request as that's a lot of data transformation work to ask of your API consumers. I can see two valid and opposing arguments:

- It's borderline bad practice to allow them to create/update with data where you're only accepting *some* of the properties but silently ignoring others (i.e. they can PUT with a different `id` than they received and you're just silently ignoring it could potentially give them a false sense of the actual state of the collection/resource)
- The adage *"be liberal about what you accept and strict about what you generate"* would dictate that properties that are superfluous to the schema that your API defines can safely be ignored without generating any errors for the client. So someone could do a GET, then modify the `id`, then do a POST/PUT and you would simply ignore the `id` property.

If I had to choose one, I'd probably go with the second option because I think it makes for a simpler, more symmetrical experience for your API consumers in that they can do a full circle GET, POST/PUT the GET response, and GET again to receive the same original response. Additionally, your API consumers can't really complain about implementation behavior for data that goes beyond the defined schema since you're already off the beaten path of standardization.